# Read all registry keys in subfolder WSH

Tags: javascript, windows, vbscript, registry

I am trying to read all the registry keys below this path:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

Under that folder there are a list of GUIDs that I want to get

Edit - I cannot use .Net

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REG.exe QUERY command and capture the results (see this page: http://www.rgagnon.com/wshdetails/wsh-0017.html)

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```